# In Espresso, how to use action params in templates without assign them to instance variables?

Tags: ruby

I have a lot of actions that receives params via method arguments:

```
class App < E
  map '/'

  def read page
    @page = page
    # etc.
    render
  end

  def profile user
    @user = user
    # etc.
    render
  end
end
```

How do i access `page`, `user` etc. in templates without assign them to instance variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 2 options here.

Most straightforward one is to use `action_params`:

```
def read page
  # use action_params[:page] in templates
end
```

Please note this works only with Ruby 1.9

In Ruby 1.8 use `action_params[0]`

Another way is to pass your params as context variables:

```
def profile user
  render :user => user
  # in templates, user is available as #user getter
  # rather than @user instance variable
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, if you pass a hash to the render function, it will assign those keys as local variables to the view.  Something like

```
render(:foo => "Bar")
```

in the action, and then in the view you could do

```
<%= foo %>
```

Which would render

```
Bar
```